# mysql Time Difference Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query where I have to calculate the time difference in minutes but I need seconds as well. So, can I use 6.10 stating 6 minutes 10 seconds in the following query? OR is there any alternative to state this?

Query:

```
select distinct(users) , avisitedDate from visitSearchEngine vs
WHERE vs.users!=' ' 
AND vs.status='0' 
AND vs.hitType='googleIdentified'
AND vs.avisitedDate>'2012-12-06' 
AND ((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),vs.avisitedDate)))/60)>=5
AND ((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),vs.avisitedDate)))/60)<6.10
```

Please provide me suggestions!

Thanks,

Comment: why don't you Convert all the values to Seconds ??

Comment: @Joddy ... silly me!! got psycho man due to heavy work!!! thanks.. it would have been done converting into seconds!! sorry for troubling!!

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct(users) , avisitedDate from visitSearchEngine vs
WHERE vs.users!=' ' 
AND vs.status='0' 
AND vs.hitType='googleIdentified'
AND vs.avisitedDate>'2012-12-06' 
AND TIMEDIFF(NOW(),vs.avisitedDate) >= '00:05:00'
AND TIMEDIFF(NOW(),vs.avisitedDate) < '00:06:10'
```